# Find the distribution of $X=U^2$ for a random variable $U$ on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[-1,1]$. Let $X=U^2$. Find the distribution of $X$.

This is what I have right now.

$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x) = P(U^2 \leq x) \rightarrow P(-\sqrt{x} \leq U \leq \sqrt{x})$.

$$F(x)= \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x <0, \\
  \sqrt{x}, & \text{if }  0 \leq x < 1\\
  1, & \text{if } x \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined for negative values

Comment: then that is why it is 0 if x is less than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $\sqrt{x}$ right. But, the intervals are wrong.

$F_x(x)=P(U^2 \leq x)=P(-\sqrt{x} \leq U\leq\sqrt{x})=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}dt$

$F_x(x)=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}U(t)dt=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2}dt=\sqrt{x}$

$$F_x(x)=\begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x < 0, \\
  \sqrt{x}, & \text{if }  0 \leq x < 1\\
  1, & \text{if } x \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Hope it is clear.

Comment: How did you get $P(\sqrt{x} \leq U \leq \sqrt{x})$ shouldn't it be $\pm\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: "Hope it is clear" Clearly marred with typos, yes. Please revise carefully your post.

Comment: @Killercamin, you are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: One last question, why was [-1,1] important then?

Comment: With the new random variable, we do not have negative values, as we have mapped them all to the interval $[0,1]$. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you now it makes sense

Comment: I made an edit. Sorry I was being clumsy

Comment: Now, it is very nice (+1). I would still suggest that you spell out for future readers that the $U(t)=1/2$ inside the integral is the pdf of the uniform $U(-1,1)$, or $f_X=\frac{1}{1-(-1)}.$